# Ionic Cordova run iOS from the terminal is not working

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, simulator

I'm trying to run the ionic 2 application on the simulator from the terminal using the following command line `ionic cordova run ios`.

The application is built successfully and the simulator is showing up!

But the application is not installed and I got the following error inside the terminal

> The request to open "com.curlybrackets.rnbemitter" failed. The request
>   was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace) for reason: NotFound
>   ("Application "com.curlybrackets.rnbemitter" is unknown to
>   FrontBoard"). Underlying error (domain=FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain,
>   code=4):  The operation couldn’t be completed. Application
>   "com.curlybrackets.rnbemitter" is unknown to FrontBoard.  Application
>   "com.curlybrackets.rnbemitter" is unknown to FrontBoard.
>   com.curlybrackets.rnbemitter: -1

I'm using the following versions:

- cordova 8.0.0
- ionic cli 4.0.1

Any idea why the error above occurred?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem running the Simulator from Terminal. I have fixed that by opening my project on Xcode and starting the Simulator from there (just run the app).

It had to do that only once. After that, app always starts correctly from Terminal.